# Android Studio has strange high contrast in code part

Tags: android-studio

I didn't do anything special in the Android Studio settings, but suddenly when running, the part where the code is located took on a strange contrast that even themes can't change.

[image]

I reinstalled Android Studio, but the problem still remains. Other designs look the same.